# 'null is not an object(evaluating'e.region')' react-native-maps. Error is located in the index.android.bundle file

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to implement react-native-maps and come up with this error. i have used this component before without the error described in the title. This is all in one class component which I then export.

```
componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        ({ coords }) => {
            const { latitude, longitude } = coords

            this.setState({
                position: {
                    latitude,
                    longitude,
                },
                region: {
                    latitude,
                    longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                },
            })
        },
        (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
    )
}

render() {

    const { region, position } = this.state

    return (
        <View>
            <MapView
                style={styles.map}
                region={region}
            >
                {position && (
                    <MapView.Circle
                        center={position}
                        radius={300}
                        strokeColor={'transparent'}
                        fillColor={'rgba(112,185,213,0.30)'}
                    />
                )}
                {position && (
                    <MapView.Circle
                        center={position}
                        radius={100}
                        strokeColor={'transparent'}
                        fillColor={'#3594BC'}
                    />
                )}
            </MapView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: What does your default `state` look like? 

You're calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` in `componentDidMount` so depending on what state looks like,`region` could possibly be `null` at the time of rendering. Also note that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous so even if you call it earlier, `region` could still be null by time it attempts to render. So you should default `region` to some value.

Comment: thanks @MichaelCheng, I had realised it was my state....simply "state = {}" fixed it

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must get access to location permission in android
second change

```
 { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
```

to this :

```
{ enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 5000 }
```